# Passing items(or other variables) to middleware (or other modules) of scrapy.

Tags: scrapy

I'm improving the spider I wrote a few months ago. I'm trying to make it smarter and download only the new information from the website. For the purpose I am adding a code in the Download Middleware module to check whether URL ID is already visited or not. Except the URL which I can get fairly easy with request.url command I need to pass an Item from the Spider - that Item is the Date Last Updated.

The idea is to compare both values(URL and Date Last Update) with the ones from the database (regular csv file) and if both are the same to drop the request, if both are missing or if Last Update date doesn't match to proceed with the request.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the Item from the Spider to the Middleware. I can see that in the Pipelines module (object) is passed to the class, tried to add it in Middleware class but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to pass an Item or any other variable from the Spider to the Middleware module?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you pass any additional info in the request meta as `request.meta['my_thing'] = ...` or as an argument `yield Request(url, meta={'my_thing': ...})`, which all middlewares up in the chain will be able to access. For your case however I'd recommend either to use scrapy built in cache middleware on dummy policy or either one of these two modules which do exactly the thing you have in mind:
https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-crawl-once
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch

Comment: I will check those modules for sure, I already checked deltafetch but since I'm not an experienced developer I failed to understand how to implement it properly in my spider. That's why I'm trying to do something by myself.
I'll move back to those modules again but I would like to also complete the idea I have.

Comment: I am using meta in the yield command to pass Items from different parse-methods in my spider, but how I should use a request.meta['some_item']? I have an item called "url_id", but when I try to load it in DownloadMiddleware > process_request with request.meta['url_id'] it gives me KeyError: 'url_id'

Comment: You can also pass meta as an argument of request. See this snippet: https://hastebin.com/apaloyinun.py

Comment: I can successfully pass the meta-information in the spider-file itself. The issue is that I cannot pass it from the spider to the download-middleware.
Here is a stripped down version of my project:
https://github.com/sdraganov/scrapy_meta

There are two Items in the items.py file, those are loaded into spiders > meta.py file. There are two parse functions, the first one passes arguments to the second one via the meta attribute. The same thing however doesn't in the  Downloaded middleware, if you uncomment meta line you get an error.

Comment: Ah, I see, your middleware runs on *all* requests (including initial from `start_urls` which won't have any meta set). So just do `if 'item' in request.meta` check in the `process_request` method (also, you don't need to mark it as `@classmethod`).

Comment: God bless you!!! Yeah I actually didn't realize that, now it works as expected. I'll see how it will fit into my original project however - I'm using ItemLoader there and don't know if the same thing will work there: here is an extraction of the ItemLoader: https://pastebin.com/40HfvQUX

Comment: ItemLoader is a short lived object, when you call `loader.load_item()` it returns plain old static item which is same thing as in you example github code. So better rename the "itemLoader" key back to simply "item" to not confuse yourself.

Comment: Would you please confirm what exactly should I remove from my code since I'm confused. I'm using itemLoader since I'm adding input and output processors to get the scraped data into the desired format. I won't be able to do that with just Items. Should I remove itemLoader completely or you meant something else?

Comment: Meant replacing `meta={'itemLoader': forum_loader.load_item()}` to `meta={'item': forum_loader.load_item()}` in the spider code. When you are calling `.load_item()` it returns a simple item which is not an item loader anymore.